# MySql conditional view

Tags: mysql, view, multiple-tables

I want to create a MySql view that includes a value only if another value is present and not null in several other tables.  I can picture a long complex query use 'NOT IN' or JOINS but I wanted to get some feedback on the best way to do this.  Imagine something like the following:
I have several tables like so:

```
T1   T2   T3
id   id   id
data1   data2   data3
```

Etc.  Maybe 8 tables like that.  The id is the key that all the tables share in common.  Then I want a view that will display only the id collumn if, and only if, the id is present in all of the above tables, and the value of the data from that table is not null in the row with that id.

Thanks

Comment: The best way to do it is using a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inner join`s to display only records that are in all tables

```
select t1.id
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join t3 on t1.id = t3.id
where data1 is not null 
and data2 is not null 
and data3 is not null
```

Comment: That will give me the data though.  All I want is the id.  Can I just change the first part of the select statement to say 'SELECT ID' ?